# My Sql Date comparision including given date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have date stored as updatedOn (values like '2012-11-12 12:38:43')

My queries is:

```
select * from mytable 
where updatedOn >= '11/12/2012' AND updatedOn <= '11/12/2012'
```

My goal is to get all records inclusive given `from` & `to` dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you avoid `<=` and use `<` instead, you end up being forced to use logic that works regardless of whether or not your data has a time component.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  myTable
WHERE
      updatedOn >= '2012-12-11'
  AND updatedOn <  '2012-12-11' + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) component of your `updatedOn` column and format your date literals in one of [the formats supported by MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  DATE(updatedOn) BETWEEN '2012-12-11'
                           AND '2012-12-11'
```

Or else, use MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert your strings to MySQL dates:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  DATE(updatedOn) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('11/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y')
                           AND STR_TO_DATE('11/12/2012', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: If the `UpdatedOn` field is indexed, and you want to use that index, you should ***never*** perform a filter on `DATE(UpdatedOn)`. Your functions and manipulations need to be on the constants, not on the field you are searching. Sure, it's a tidy and convenient way of typing the logic out, but it will destroy the optimiser's ability to use indexes for that filter.

Comment: @Dems: Agreed.  Your answer is more index-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try

```
select * from mytable 
where updatedOn >= '11/12/2012' AND updatedOn <= '11/12/2012 23:59:59.999'
```

As when you write `'11/12/2012'` it means `'11/12/2012 00:00:00'`, so you also need to add the time to the string

EDIT: as @Dems pointed out I also needed to take milli seconds into account

Comment: What about `11/12/2012 23:59:59.01`?  Or `11/12/2012 23:59:59.001`?

Comment: What about `11/12/2012 23:59:59.9991`? I was trying to point out that using `<=` will only ever be as accurate as you parameter. If you use `< '12/12/2012'` instead, there is never an accuracy consideration. It just works. Always.  *[Using `<=` is like doing `WHERE x >= 1 AND x <= 1.999999999999999999` instead of `WHERE x >= 1 AND x < 2`]*

Comment: I think that mysql only stores date/time with precision of 1 millisecond, but I agree with you, your answer is more accurate and elegant, I was just providing a alternative.

Comment: @Ankur: You are right about the accuracy but (the already out there) **[MariaDB](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/microseconds-in-mariadb/)** has and (the soon to be out) **[MySQL 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html)** will have microsecond accuracy.

Comment: Still, this answer is second best to Dems as an index could be used, too, with this one. I would even upvote if you used a same format for dates, like `'2012-11-12'` and not the OP's problematic `'11/12/2012'`

Answer (score 0):

You should use DATE function -

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  DATE(updatedOn) = '2012-12-11'
```

Comment: If the `UpdatedOn` field is indexed, and you want to use that index` you should ***never*** perform a filter on `DATE(UpdatedOn)`. Your functions and manipulations need to be on the constants, not on the field you are searching.  Sure, it's a tidy and convenient way of typing the logic out, but it will destroy the optimiser's ability to use indexes for that filter.